# How can I use setInterval and clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider:

```
function doKeyDown(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 32:
        /* Space bar was pressed */
        if (x == 4) {
            setInterval(drawAll, 20);
        }
        else {
            setInterval(drawAll, 20);
            x += dx;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to call **`drawAll()` once**, not creating a **loop** that call `drawAll` again and again. Should I use a recursive method for that or should I use **`clearInterval`**?

How can I use `clearInterval`?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

`setInterval` sets up a *recurring* timer. It returns a handle that you can pass into `clearInterval` to stop it from firing:

```
var handle = setInterval(drawAll, 20);

// When you want to cancel it:
clearInterval(handle);
handle = 0; // I just do this so I know I've cleared the interval
```

On browsers, the handle is guaranteed to be a number that isn't equal to `0`; therefore, `0` makes a handy flag value for "no timer set". (Other platforms may return other values; Node.js's timer functions return an object, for instance.)

To schedule a function to *only* fire once, use `setTimeout` instead. It won't keep firing. (It also returns a handle you can use to cancel it via `clearTimeout` before it fires that one time if appropriate.)

```
setTimeout(drawAll, 20);
```

Answer (score 44):

**clearInterval** is one option:

```
var interval = setInterval(doStuff, 2000); // 2000 ms = start after 2sec 
function doStuff() {
  alert('this is a 2 second warning');
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Side note – if you want to use separate functions to set & clear interval, the interval variable have to be accessible for all of them, in 'relative global', or 'one level up' scope:

```
var interval = null;    

function startStuff(func, time) {
    interval = setInterval(func, time);
}

function stopStuff() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I used [Angular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_(web_framework)) with [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)).

In my case, `setInterval` returns a Node.js Timer object. Which, when I called `clearInterval(timerobject)`, did not work.

I had to get the id first and call *clearInterval*:

`clearInterval(timerobject._id)`

Answer (score 9):

Use `setTimeout(drawAll, 20)` instead. That only executes the function once.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but setTimeout is finishing the loop at each point, I use other approach and its working fine,  function doKeyDown(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
          case 32:  /* Space bar was pressed */
              loop = setInterval(drawAll, 20);
              if (x == 202) {
                  x = 400;
                  spinner();
              }
              break;
          }
      }

Comment: it wasn't the question tho

Answer (score 0):

If we have to use timers, it's best to use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

This way the memory consumption stays low, and **browser tabs won't freeze much overtime**.

However there is an issue: the loops are not well cadenced, the next loop does run after all tasks completed. See the time loops are not equal and are increasing, little by little:

[image]

```js
const timer = setTimeout(function tick(){
  console.log("Hi!")
  // <-- More jobs here -->
  setTimeout(tick, 2000);
}, 2000);
```

We wouldn't try to create some music in this manner.

---

A proper more modern way is to NOT use `interval` or `timeout` at all, but instead to continuously check the date epoch and proceed accordingly.

To do so, we can use `requestAnimationFrame`.

In this example, the next loop will be triggered AFTER all functions complete.

This does replace `setInterval` very well and is more flexible, however this is still not optimal regarding the cadence, after many loops, the intervals are still shifting!!!

```js
/* Countdown loop ----------------------------------------*/
let job = null, origin = new Date().getTime()
const timer = () => {
  if (new Date().getTime() - 2000 > origin){
   console.log("Hi!")
   origin = new Date().getTime()
   job = requestAnimationFrame(timer)
  } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(timer)    
  }
}

/* Start looping -----------------------------------------*/
requestAnimationFrame(timer)
```

---

**To completely solve both issues:**

The loops are well cadenced, and we don't bother with `setInterval` any more. Every devices will adapt, they will just slow down their `animationFrame` rate at their own cadence, but still be on time.

[image]

```js
/* Timer loop ----------------------------------------*/
let job, origin = new Date().getTime(), i = 0;
const timer = () => {
  if (new Date().getTime() - i > origin){
   console.log("Hi!")
   i = i + 2000
   job = requestAnimationFrame(timer)
  } else if (job !== null){
      requestAnimationFrame(timer)    
  }
}

/* Start looping or start again ------------------------*/
requestAnimationFrame(timer)
// Stop the loop
// job = null
```