# How to output a variable from setInterval

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval, clearinterval

I have got code like this:

```
var a = 5;
var i = setInterval(timer, 1000); 

function timer() {
    if (a < 1) {
        console.log('Reaching Stop');      
        clearInterval(i);

        var endInterval="ok";

    }
    a -= 1;
}
console.log(endInterval);
```

And the problem is:

How to output `endInterval` from `setInterval`?

Comment: HI@Chris You should add a callback inside the timer function, Means when your condition satisfies then it will return the value of endInterval. Is this what you want?

Comment: Your question is answered in [Wait until setInterval() is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055530/wait-until-setinterval-is-done)

Comment: If you declare the var inside this scope.. cannot had access outside the function