# Run JavaScript function at regular time interval

Tags: javascript

I am currently building a website to host software. What I want is to add to the project pages is a slideshow of screenshots cycling, changing images about every 5 seconds. Is there any way to a script triggered at a time interval using just JavaScript? ..or will I have to resort to alternative methods for achieving my desired functionality. 
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [set Interval and Clear Interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/set-interval-and-clear-interval)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval):

```
function doSomething() {
    alert('This pops up every 5 seconds and is annoying!');
}

setInterval(doSomething, 5000); // Time in milliseconds
```

Pass it the function you want called repeatedly every *n* milliseconds. (`setTimeout`, by the way, will call a function with a timeout.)

If you ever want to stop the timer, hold onto `setInterval`’s return value and pass it to [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval).

Answer (score 19):

You want the `setInterval` function.

```
setInterval(function() {
  // This will be executed every 5 seconds
}, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds
```

Basic reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp (please ignore the reference to the "lang" parameter)

More indepth reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval

Comment: Yeah, this is true. I'll replace with a better one.

Comment: W3schools may not be the most accurate but it's easier on mind and eyes. Beside who is just discovering about setinterval would greatly benefit from not seeing c code, getting to try it in browser, and get a organize reference.

Comment: Ok fine I have both now :P

Comment: So just because something is not accurate but easy to read makes it a good resource? That's like walking into a classroom expecting to be taught physics but learning how to bake bread and being satisfied with the outcome

Comment: sure its not as definitive at places and misleading, but saying everything there is wrong is a BIG assumption. For basic stuff is more than enough. Also as i said, best stepping stone for someone just learning. When in doubt go to MDN.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: As you said, it’s misleading, and I’d say that “almost right” is a terrible stepping stone. Time to find the Meta question!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Sample usage:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    console.log("foo");
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It Changes the date time in a div and time changes frequently after 1 sec.

```
    setInterval(function(){
      var date=new Date();
      $('.class').html(date);
    },1000);
```