# How to execute function on specific interval of time in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to execute function in angular on a specific time interval and how can we stop that too. Please give me solution for that.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far. What have you found in your research?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript function at regular time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070659/run-javascript-function-at-regular-time-interval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to be about JavaScript in general, not specifically Angular.
You could use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to execute a function on a fixed interval:

```js
// Will print each second
let interval = setInterval(() => console.log("I am a text"), 1000)

// Stops the interval
clearInterval(interval)
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval