# Fetch data from an API in regular interval in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I want to fetch data from an API in regular interval. I wrote a script which is fetching data successfully but how to repeat this step for infinite time, so that I can fetch data in regular interval.

I want to fetch data in the interval of 1sec, what should I do?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const time = new Date()

function saveData(metrics) {
  console.log(time.getSeconds())
  console.log(metrics)
  console.log(time.getSeconds())
}

const getData = () => {
  fetch('http://example.com/api/v1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(saveData)
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

getData()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript function at regular time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070659/run-javascript-function-at-regular-time-interval)

Comment: Just a side note: maybe I misunderstood your aim but it looks to me that it does not make a lot of sens to declare `const time = new Date()` outside the `saveData()` function, if it has to be executed at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Just use it like this

```js
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  getData();
}, 1000);
```

If you want to avoid making wrapper callback like above, you can just pass getData as a callback, which setInterval will call after each specified interval time i.e 1 second here

```
const interval = setInterval(getData, 1000);
```

Comment: Seems to be a nice solution for this problem. A shorter solution might be `const interval = setInterval(getData, 1000)` but I don't think you get any benefit from using the shorter version of this code. I just wanted to mention that.

Comment: @Nope, you are right, we can just pass the getData as a callback to the setInterval, which it will call after each specified interval. I have just wrapped getData with my own callback, wanted to make it more readable to OP

Comment: @Nope, added your suggestion too

Comment: Are both solutions asynchronous (because of the callbacks)? So I could have several functions set up like this in the same file going off at different intervals?