# How do I set delays in template pasting scripts?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a script where while var < 1, it pastes letters, but it makes my screen crash. I tried seeing some questions here on StackOverflow, but the code doesn't line up with mine. I want the interval to be every 2 milliseconds

My code:

```html
<template>
  a
</template>
<html>
 <head>a</head>
 <body onLoad="pasteContent()">
  
 </body>

  <script>
    while (true) {
      function pasteContent() {
        var i = 0;
        var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];
        var clon = temp.content.cloneNode(true);
        document.body.appendChild(clon);
      }
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run JavaScript function at regular time interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070659/run-javascript-function-at-regular-time-interval)

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout? Just set the timeout to 2 since it uses milliseconds.

Here's an article on it: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Still doesn't work. Do you have any code specifically related to my script?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()`:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('.div')
let intervalId = setInterval(writeLetter, 1000)

function writeLetter(){
  if(div.innerHTML === 'aaaa'){
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }else{
    div.innerHTML += 'a'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='div'></div>
```