# Slider Infinite loop stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code. It works "good". But if it loops for sometime, the page crashes. Also I cannot think of a way how to stop looping it when a button is clicked. Any ideas?

Cannot give a jsfiddle demo, because it crashes.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stop = false;

    function ivSlider($element, $continue) {
        var current = $element.find('.current');
        var next = current.next();
        if (next.length == 0) next = $element.find(">:first-child");
        setInterval(function () {
            current.removeClass('current');
            next.addClass('current');
            if ($continue === true) ivSlider($element, true);
        }, 4000);
    }

    ivSlider($('.slider'), true);

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider li {
    display: none;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.current {
    display: block!important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li class="current">Slide 1</li>
    <li>Slide 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`. As it is now, you have a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).
As for stopping the loop, you never set `$continue` to `false`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var stop = false;
    var timeout = null;

    function ivSlider($element, $continue) {
        var current = $element.find('.current');
        var next = current.next();
        if (next.length == 0) {
            next = $element.find(">:first-child");
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            current.removeClass('current');
            next.addClass('current');
            if ($continue === true) {
                ivSlider($element, true);
            }
        }, 4000);
    }

    ivSlider($('.slider'), true);
    $('.stop-button').click(function () {
        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I make a button. And do something like $('.stop-button').click(function() { //what should I do here to stop oit });

Comment: See my edit in the answer. That is if you want to stop the timeout immediately. If you want to execute last scheduled timeout function till the `if` block, then you should use your `stop` variable instead of `$continue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**clearInterval**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval) to stop it.  Here I Would like to quote [**@T.J. Crowder's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978560/1671639),

> **`setInterval`** sets up a *recurring* timer. It returns a handle that
>   you can pass into **`clearInterval`** to stop it from firing.

you can try like this

1) stay with the boolean value `stop`.

2) Have a separate method for animation.

```
   function animation() {
       current.removeClass('current');
       next.addClass('current');
       if ($continue === true) ivSlider($element, true);
   }
```

3) **Enclose with a separate function with a parameter** and set a variable for `setInterval`.

```
function yourFunc(stop) {
    if (stop) {
       interval = setInterval(animation, 4000);
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(interval); // STOP the animation loop
    }
}
```

4) On button click, **pass the `false` as parameter to stop animation**.

```
 $('button').click(function () {
     yourFunc(false);
 }
```

---

**Update from your comments:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     function animation() {
         var current = $('.slider').find('.current');
         var next = current.next();
         if (next.length == 0) next = $('.slider').find(">:first-child");
         current.removeClass('current');
         next.addClass('current');
         ivSlider($('.slider'), true);
     }

     function yourFunc(stop) {
         if (stop) {
             interval = setInterval(animation, 1000);
         } else {
             alert('Im going to be stopped')
             clearInterval(interval); // STOP the animation loop
         }
     }

     $('button').on('click', function () {
         yourFunc(false);
     });

     yourFunc(true);
 });
```

Check out this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/59WSs/2/)

Comment: This is my current JS: http://pastebin.com/NCV7PVGE based on your answer. But it seems animation to be never called.

Comment: @FakeHeal There was a little logic missing check this out http://jsfiddle.net/59WSs/1/