# Display current time from javascript count up timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

This is my code:

```
function timer() {
var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var totalSeconds = 0;
setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
        return "0" + valString;
    } else {
        return valString;
    }
}
};
```

When the user clicks a button, this function will be called and this code simply creates a timer in format XX : XX (minutes, seconds), and that's ok.

What I want is when the user clicks another button, an alert box to display saying at which time was it clicked (depending on the timer, how far it went) and then stop the timer.

How can I do this with javascript or jQuery?

Comment: To stop time you can use [clearInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp). Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/set-interval-and-clear-interval is a good read

Comment: why are you defining two function inside timer()..i dont see any benefit?

Comment: @BlazE Did either answer help you or are you looking for additional functionality?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yes, your answers has helped me, I fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like some commenters mentioned, you should use `clearInterval` to stop the timer. You pass it the value returned by `setInterval` in `timer`.

You're already storing the minutes and seconds, so just use those DOM elements:

For instance, a function called `clearTimer`:

```
function clearTimer() {
    if (timer_handle) {
        clearInterval(timer_handle);
    }
    alert(document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML + ':' + document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML);
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tupton/Xu27j/). Note that I removed some of the closures you had in your original code; it should work either way but I think it's a bit cleaner to use separate functions.

You also may want to check that a timer handle doesn't already exist when clicking the button to start the timer. If you don't, a second timer will start and the handle you save will override the first. You won't be able to stop the first timer if this happens.

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7M7u4/1/) is a working fiddle.

If all you want to do it stop the timer and display how long it has been since the timer started it is really simple with what you have already. Just add:

```
function stop(){
  alert(   
    pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60))+
    ":"+
    pad(totalSeconds%60)
  );
}
```

And a button with the `onclick="stop()"`.

I moved your code around because it looked a little off.

```
var totalSeconds = 0;

var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
var stepper = setInterval(setTime, 1000);

function setTime() {
  ++totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
}

function pad(val) {
  var valString = val + "";
  if (valString.length < 2) {
    return "0" + valString;
  } else {
    return valString;
  }
}

function stop(){
  clearInterval(stepper);
  alert(   
    pad(parseInt(totalSeconds/60))+
    ":"+
    pad(totalSeconds%60)
  );
}
```