# How does clearInterval() works?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I the given code, I am using `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` methods.
Here are two buttons for `setInterval()` and two for `clearInterval()`, if I click both `setInterval()` buttons, then the `clearInterval()` buttons doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<div id="a"></div>

<button id='bt1'>start</button>
<button id='bt2'>Stop</button>
<button id='bt3'>Start</button>
<button id='bt4'>Stop</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var Graph = {
graph: null,
start: function (i) {
    this.graph = setInterval(function () {
        $('#a').html(i++);
    }, 1000);
},
stop: function () {
    window.clearInterval(this.graph);
}
};
$('#bt1').click(function(){
   Graph.start(1);
});
$('#bt2').click(function(){
   Graph.stop();
});
$('#bt3').click(function(){
   Graph.start(1);
});
$('#bt4').click(function(){
   Graph.stop();
});
```

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/ku5nk/2/)

Comment: Just put the following line of code before the `setInterval()` call in the `start()` method. This will stop the previous running timer: `if (this.graph) { this.stop(); }` See my [edited answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108579/how-does-clearinterval-works/21108832#21108832) for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers, the first timer ID is overwritten. Try to store the IDs separately in an array or at least as separate variable names. Here is one adjustment using an array:

```
var Graph = {
graph: [0, 0],                               /// turn this into an array
start: function(id, i) {                     /// add a new parameter here
    this.graph[id] = setInterval(function () {
        $('#a').html(i++);
    }, 1000);
},
stop: function (id) {                        /// add parameter here as well
    window.clearInterval(this.graph[id]);
}
};
$('#bt1').click(function(){
   Graph.start(0, 1);                        /// set index 0 with this timer id
});
$('#bt2').click(function(){
   Graph.stop(0);                            /// stop using id at index 0
});
$('#bt3').click(function(){
   Graph.start(1, 1);                        /// etc.
});
$('#bt4').click(function(){
   Graph.stop(1);
});
```

Your `i` variable may be subject to the same thing depending on what you try; I haven't addressed that here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works perfect, but I didn't understand why is graph an array with length '2' ?

Answer (score 1):

You only have a single variable to store the result of both calls to `setInterval`, i.e. you are overwriting it on the second call so the first timer can't be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

The `clearInterval()` method clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.

The ID value returned by `setInterval()` is used as the parameter for the `clearInterval()` method.

**Note:** To be able to use the `clearInterval()` method, you must use a global variable when creating the interval method:

```
myVar = setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);
```

Then you will be able to stop the execution by calling the clearInterval() method.

You can also refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978560/1419801)

Answer (score 0):

If you click the #bt1 button and then the #bt3 button, the second `start()` function call will overwrite the `graph` variable in the `Graph` object. So the ID value returned by first `setInterval()` call is lost, you cannot clear the first timer.

Just put the following line of code before the `setInterval()` call in the `start()` method. This will stop the previous running timer:

```
if (this.graph) { this.stop(); }
```

Like this:

```
var Graph = {
graph: null,
start: function (i) {
    if (this.graph) { this.stop(); }
    this.graph = setInterval(function () {
        $('#a').html(i++);
    }, 1000);
},
stop: function () {
    window.clearInterval(this.graph);
}
};
$('#bt1').click(function(){
   Graph.start(1);
});
$('#bt2').click(function(){
   Graph.stop();
});
$('#bt3').click(function(){
   Graph.start(1);
});
$('#bt4').click(function(){
   Graph.stop();
});
```