# How to add set intervals to polling script

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, polling

We have an ajax system setup to check for unread messages during different events using a chrome browser:

```
var JHR = function ( method, url, data, fun ) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseJSON = null;

  // xhr.open( 'POST', url );
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + data.userAuth);
  xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );

  xhr.addEventListener( 'load',  function () {
    //my old man once told me "Zirak, sometimes, you must face the dangers
    // of life head on". he then threw me in a shark tank. but I'm sure it
    // applies here too.
    //...I was only 7
    xhr.responseJSON = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );

    if (fun) fun( xhr.responseJSON, xhr );
  });

  xhr.send( JSON.stringify(data) );

  return xhr;
};


var pollInterval = 1*60*60; // 60 min
var timerId;

function startRequest() {
    updateBadge();
    timerId = window.setTimeout(startRequest, pollInterval);
}
function stopRequest() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
}

function getUnreadCount(onSuccess, onError) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get("userAuth", function(data) {
    var response = JHR("GET", "https://api.rss.com/v2/unread_entries.json", {userAuth: data.userAuth}); 
    console.log(response);
  }); 
}

function updateBadge() {
    // Callbacks for onSuccess, and onError
    getUnreadCount(function(data) {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:data.unreadItems});
    }, function(data){
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:'error'});
    });
}
```

We would like to set a variable for an interval (every 5 minutes for example) and only send the ajax call out every 5 minutes or whatever the variable might be set to.

Can someone help us determine where to add this behavior?  I thought the pollInterval would handle it but it doesn't.

Comment: Why don't you change `window.setTimeout` to `windows.setInterval` (and clearInterval as well)?

Comment: Thanks good suggestion, how could the clearInterval work?

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` has the same signature, you just have to change the function name in your code.

Comment: I would actually stick with setTimeout and just call the polling function in a setTimeout again in the complete callback of every xhr request. With setInterval + latency you could run the risk of overlapping eventually (not very likely with a 60 minute interval, but still)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a onreadystatechange function to your xhr object to just call the function again upon completion. Inside your JHR declaration:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
    timerId && clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = setTimeout(startRequest, pollInterval);
  }
}
```

If you were to use setInterval instead you should check the previous xhr object for completion (via its readyState property) before firing another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to use `clearInterval`:

```
var pollInterval = 1*60*60; // 60 min
var timerId;

function startRequest() {
    updateBadge();
    timerId = window.setInterval(startRequest, pollInterval);
}

function stopRequest() {
    window.clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

More about `setInterval`:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval

[setInterval and how to use clearInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/set-interval-and-clear-interval)

Comment: Thanks, I don't think stopRequest is being called anywhere.  Where do you recommend I call it from?