# Replying to comments in a comment system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a comment system where a user can post a comment and a reply can be dropped on that comment. since a comment system is mostly contacted i decided to  put the query that grabs the comments in a seperate php file(ajax/asr.php) and then use the `setInterval` function to load this file periodically so the user sees fresh comments.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.responses').load('ajax/asr.php',{id:<?PHP echo $id?>});
    },1000);
</script>
```

Each comment has a reply buton which shows the reply form.

My problem is: Whenever i decide to reply to a comment, the reply form disappears shortly due to the `setInterval`. I want the `setInterval` to pause when a user clicks the reply button, and then after he replies (submits the reply form) it can continue.

Comment: Just clear the interval `var example = setInterval(function(){ /* your code */ }, 1000);`, then when the user clicks the reply button `clearInterval(example);`. You can then start the interval again. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/set-interval-and-clear-interval

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` function returns a value that is a reference to that particular timer. You can use this to pass to the `clearInterval` function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) which will then stop that interval from occuring.

so in your above code you would assign the return from your setInterval function to a variable you can access from wherever you need (eg a global variable). Then when you open the edit form you can just clear that interval.

Then of course when you have finished or cancelled commenting you will need to restart the interval timer (which would of course have been moved into a handy function).