# Clearing intervals javascript

Tags: javascript, function, intervals

I would be intrested how I can clear these intervals. I have tried clearInterval() but it didn't work don't shout at me I am new in javascript. If you can clear those intervals I would be so happy. Function called gameOver() should stop them.

```
function startGame(){

spawnLadybug();
newGame();
clearInterval();
setInterval(function(){moveLadybug()}, 250);
setInterval(function(){spawnWall()}, 5000);
spawnFood();

}
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation, which explains exactly how to do this?

Comment: I'm shouting at ya ! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [setInterval and how to use clearInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval)  identifier so you can call [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) on it later on:

```
// set Up interval
var IntervalId = window.setInterval(function(){console.log('looping !');}, 250);
// Cancel interval
window.clearInterval(IntervalId);
```

For completeness' sake, if there are users of AngularJS around, the syntax is nearly the same with the [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) service:

```
var IntervalId = $interval(function(){console.log('looping !');},250);
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(IntervalId); });
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear an interval you have to save the return value of the setInterval function and use that to clear it like so:

```
var moveBugInterval = setInterval(function(){moveLadybug()}, 250);
...
clearInterval(moveBugInterval);
```

Comment: This seems to work but I wonder how I do set those intervals in a function. So I could have one function clearing them and one starting them?

Comment: You have to declare the variable in the scope that both functions can see like so:http://pastebin.com/xC7pi8AZ.