# how to change text when coundown zero

Tags: javascript, php

Hello my countdown not Stop at zero i need to change my test when countdown going to zero, This countdown start again after zero value i need to replace value after countdown is zero .....  $countdown = 50

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var start = Date.now(),
    diff,
    minutes,
    seconds;
function timer() {
    // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
    // startTimer() was called
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

    if (diff <= 0) {
        // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
        // example 05:00 not 04:59
        start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
};
// we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
timer();
setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
var fiveMinutes = <?php echo $countdown?>

    display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
  };
```

PHP In body

```
     if ($countdown>3){
        echo "Next Submit: Wait <span id='time'></span>";
    }else{
    echo "Next Submit: READY....!";
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the `setInterval()` call to a variable.

`var myTimer = setInterval();`

This way you can reference it later. Then, you can have a call within your function to check for a certain condition (in your case when the countdown reaches 0) and then use `clearInterval()` to end the timer.

[Topic covering clearInterval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval)

Comment: Would need to see the code that is clearing the interval to help. Make sure you are clearing the interval after you are done with the updates.