# How to stop calling ajax request on button click using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I ajax request thats calling funkcija2.php every 5 min

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
  function callMe2()
    {
        $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "funkcija2.php",
               data: "id=2",
               success: function(response){
                          $("#badge2").html(response);
                        }
       });
    }

    // Call function
    callMe2();
    setInterval(callMe2, 300000); // Poziv 300 sec - 5 min              
  </script>
```

and i have 2 jquery functions that are toggle-ing divs. They look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".csgol2").click(function()
    {
        $(".list-inline2").toggle("slow");
        $(".row").width( "100%" );
    });
}); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".csgol1").click(function()
        {
            $(".list-inline2").toggle("slow");
            $(".row").width( "70%" );
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

How can i add in these jquery functions that they stop and start calling this ajax request ?

Comment: dont understand what your asking

Comment: Could you use clearinterval to remove the recurring interval after someone clicks the button? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `clearInterval()` function you can simply end the loop.

Comment: and how do i start it again ?