# clearInterval() doesn't work and I can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, onclick, cleartimeout

I'm trying to add `play/pause` button to a timer with a function that decides what to do based on the value of **isRunning**. When clicked second time my button instead of pausing, timer adds another `setTimeout` it seems and I can't figure out why.

```
var isRunning = false;

function start() {
  if(isRunning == false) {
    isRunning = true;
    setInterval(time, 1000);
    document.getElementById("play").className = "fa fa-pause";
  } 
  else if(isRunning == true) {
    isRunning = false;
    document.getElementById("play").className = "fa fa-play";
    console.log(isRunning);
    clearInterval(time);
  }
}

document.getElementById("play").onclick = start;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setInterval and how to use clearInterval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval)

Comment: var seconds = 60;
var minutes = sessionInput.value - 1;

function time() {
  seconds--;
  timer.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  if (seconds == 0) {
    minutes--;
    seconds = 60;
  }
}

@ArunGhosh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isRunning = false;
var timeoutId; // Where the timeout id will be stored.

function start() {
  if(isRunning == false) {
    isRunning = true;
    timeoutId = setInterval(time, 1000);
    document.getElementById("play").className = "fa fa-pause";
  } 
  else if(isRunning == true) {
    isRunning = false;
    document.getElementById("play").className = "fa fa-play";
    console.log(isRunning);
    clearInterval(timeoutId); // clearInterval using timeout id saved before.
  }
}

document.getElementById("play").onclick = start;
```

For more information visit https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout