# HTML - stop the timer when a code is inserted

Tags: html, timer

I created a timer that can be stoppable when the user insert a secreat code (that is 569). How can I stop the timer when the code is inserted, beacuse right now it just show "Congratulation, mission complete!"

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function () {
   minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
   seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

   minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
   seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

   display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

   if (--timer < 0) {
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You're dead";
   }
  }, 1000);
 }

  window.onload = function () {
      var Minutes = 60 * 0.5,
          display = document.querySelector('#time');
      startTimer(Minutes, display);
  };
        
        function StopFunction() {
   var code;
   var rightcode=569;
   code = document.getElementById("icode").value;
   text = (code==rightcode) ? "Congratulation, mission complete!":"Sorry, wrong code, try again!";
   if(code==rightcode){
    display = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Stop timer";}
   document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML =text;
  }
```

```css
.btn {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.success {background-color: #4CAF50;} /* Green */
.success:hover {background-color: #46a049;}
```

```html
<div id="text">You have <span id="time"></span> minutes left!</div>

<p id="text2"></p>
<br>
<p>Enter the code:</p>
<input id="icode"/>
<button class="btn success" onclick="StopFunction()">Check code</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setInterval and how to use clearInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/setinterval-and-how-to-use-clearinterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code should work for you

```
var interval;

function startTimer(duration, display) {
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        interval=setInterval(function () {
            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

            if (--timer < 0) {
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "You're dead";
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

        window.onload = function () {
            var Minutes = 60 * 0.5,
                display = document.querySelector('#time');
            startTimer(Minutes, display);
        };

        function StopFunction() {
            var code;
            var rightcode=569;
            code = document.getElementById("icode").value;
            text = (code==rightcode) ? "Congratulation, mission complete!":"Sorry, wrong code, try again!";
            if(code==rightcode){
                display = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Stop timer";}
            document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML =text;
clearInterval(interval);
        }
```

Comment: yep, it works. A little mistake clearInterval(interval) should be written in the if statement. Thanks

Comment: sorry for that i am not able to understand working of your code but i am glad that i could help you