# Autostop timer on js

Tags: javascript

A single cookie timer (meaning value) is an idea without a hitch, I want it to pause after 1 hour and start doing what it means after clicking on a motion.

Google didn't help. https://jsfiddle.net/m6vqyeu8/

Please share your version or help wrote your own.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>timer</title>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
    </head>
    <script>
        let initialValue = 0.50000096;
        let multiplier = 0.00000001;
        let getCookie = (c_name) => {

            let i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
                x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
                y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
                x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                if (x == c_name) {
                    return unescape(y);
                }
            }
        }

        let setCookie = (c_name, value, exdays) => {
            let exdate = new Date();
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
            let c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
            document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
        }

        let lastUpdated = getCookie('lastUpdated') * 1;

        if (!lastUpdated) {
            lastUpdated = Date.now();
            setCookie('lastUpdated', lastUpdated, 9999);
        }

        let diff = (Date.now() - lastUpdated) / 1000;

        let cu = (diff * multiplier) + initialValue;

        let doCu = () => {
            document.getElementById('cu').innerHTML = cu.toFixed(8);
            cu = cu + multiplier;
        }

        document.write("<div id='cu' style='text-align: center; font-size: 40pt'></div>\n");

        setInterval(doCu, 1000);
        doCu();
    </script>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey! Please refer the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425137/how-to-stop-timer-in-javascript

Comment: If you could elaborate a bit on the cookie. It is hard to understand what is the purpose of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pause and resume the counter you should save the return value of the setInterval funciton and clear it or create a new one for pause and resume. Here is the example:

```js
let interval = setInterval(doCu, 1000)
doCu()

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval)
}

function resume() {
  interval = setInterval(doCu, 1000)
}
```

Add that to the end of your script and add 2 buttons like the following in order to be able to test it.

```js
<button onclick="stop()">
  Pause
</button>
<button onclick="resume()">
  Resume
</button>
```

To stop the timer after one hour you can add the following code

```js
// Stop the timer after one hour has passed.
// setTimeout calls function stop (that is used to pause the timer aswell) after 1 hour
// 1000 milis is a second. Times 60 is a minute. Times 60 is an hour
setTimeout(stop, 1000 * 60 * 60)
```

For the timer to automatically stop after an hour from the moment you click resume change the resume function like this:

```js
function resume() {
  interval = setInterval(doCu, 1000)

  // When you resume the timer, add a timeout so it will stop in an hour.
  setTimeout(stop, 1000 * 60 * 60)
}
```

I have updated the fiddle so you can see how it is completed.

[Updated JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/ugmckwf5/1/)

EDIT:

1. Made timer stop after an hour
2. Renamed pause function to stop so it is more clear what it does.
3. Added ability to stop timer after an hour after resume

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I want the timer to stop automatically after 1 hour. Without pressing a button.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I will update the answer

Comment: Will he stop only once? Can you make it stop every hour? thank you

Comment: Glad to help. If you are happy with the answer please accept and upvote the answer.