# How to stop timer and check for value if value is not met continue and else stop timer and do something

Tags: javascript, timer

So like the title says i have this timer and i would like that once that it reaches 0, it should check if a variable called "user_energy" in this case is equal to 100. If it is than the timer will stop, and it could do something. Like for example just a console.log("It works") and if its not then it should repeat itselfs.

How would you be able to do something like that?

This is the code:

```js
function startTimer() {
var interval = 10000;
{
    localStorage.endTime = +new Date + interval;
}

if(!localStorage.endTime)
{
    startTimer();
}

setInterval(function()
{
    var remaining = localStorage.endTime - new Date;
    if( remaining >= 0 )
    {
        $('#energytimer').text( Math.floor( remaining / 1000 ) );
    } else
    {
        startTimer();
    }
}, 100);
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `localStorage` here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49425137/how-to-stop-timer-in-javascript/49425211

Comment: I want the time to be persistent so that if i refresh the page the time would still be same and not reset it self. That link is slightly helpfull, but i want to have it done with localstorage.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear how the `localStorage` stuff fits into the question, but here's a simple countdown timer that does what you are asking. You can adapt this to store the `counter` in `localStorage` if that's what you want to do.

The key is to assign a variable to the return value from the timer so that you can call `clearTimeout()` and pass that variable and stop the timer later.

```js
let timer = null; // <-- This will hold a reference to the timer

var counter = 5;

timer = setInterval(function(){
  if(counter === 0){
    clearTimeout(timer);  // Stop the timer
    console.log("Times up!");
  } else {
    $("#energytimer").text(counter--);
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="energytimer"></div>
```