# setInterval counter issue

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I  have  this  small script. My probme is that when I click the Start button the count starts normally, but if I click it again, the counter starts acting weird. How do I avoid this issue and start a fresh counter on every button click?

```js
$(".c1").click(function(e){
let a = 0;
setInterval(function(){ $("#timer").text(a);  a++; }, 500);

})
```

```css
.card{ font-size:25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


<div class="btn c1"> Start Timer</div>
<br>

<br>
<span id="timer"  class="card">0</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "acting weird" is because you're starting a **second**, separate timer, so now both are running, each putting its own copy of `a` in the element. You need to remember the previous timer's handle (the return value of `setInterval`) and cancel it (via `clearInterval`):

```js
let handle = 0;
$(".c1").click(function(e) {
  let a = 0;
  clearInterval(handle)
  handle = setInterval(function() {
    $("#timer").text(a);
    a++;
  }, 500);

})
```

```css
.card {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


<div class="btn c1"> Start Timer</div>
<br>

<br>
<span id="timer" class="card">0</span>
```

Note I've used the value `0` as the initial value of `handle` and then I've happily called `clearInterval` whether the timer was already running or not. `0` is an invalid handle value, and `clearInterval` (and `clearTimeout`) ignore invalid handle values, so you can safely do that. But add the `if` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You should reset your interval before starting the new one

```js
let interval;
$(".c1").click(function(e) {
  let a = 0;
  if(interval) clearTimeout(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#timer").text(a);  a++; }, 500);
})
```

```css
.card{ font-size:25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


<div class="btn c1"> Start Timer</div>
<br>

<br>
<span id="timer"  class="card">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the interval before starting a new one. Else, two things (or more) are incrementing `a`.

To clear an interval, just call `clearInterval` on the result of `setInterval`.

```js
let interval;

$(".c1").click(function(e){
  let a = 0;
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#timer").text(a);  a++; }, 500);

});
```

```css
.card{ font-size:25px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


<div class="btn c1"> Start Timer</div>
<br>

<br>
<span id="timer"  class="card">0</span>
```

Comment: Thanks  for  your  Answers  Good  Sir.

Answer (score 0):

every time you click you start another one **setInterval**

solution

1. when it has to count from the beginning - use `clearInterval`
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978560/3046335
2. to disable actions if we want to start the counter once - use `.attr("disabled", true);`

   ```js
   //1
       var time = 0
       $(".c1").click(function(e){
       clearInterval(time); // stop if runn interval
       let a = 0;
       time = setInterval(function(){ $("#timer").text(a);  a++; }, 500);

       })

   //2
       $(".c2").click(function(e){
       let a = 0;
       setInterval(function(){ $("#timer2").text(a);  a++; }, 500);
       $(".c2").attr("disabled", true);
       })
   ```

   ```css
       .card{ font-size:25px; }
   ```

   ```html
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


       <div class="btn c1"> Start Timer 1</div>
       <br>

       <br>
       <span id="timer"  class="card">0</span>

       <br>
       <br>
       <div class="btn c2"> Start Timer 2</div>
       <br>

       <br>
       <span id="timer2"  class="card">0</span>
   ```