# Why doesn't the state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't understand why `console.log()` works, but state still doesn't change?

Means `setState()` is called but not rendered new...

I tried async version `setState()` but it's still not working.

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {fontSize: `${20}px`};
        setInterval( 
            () => {
                console.log("ok"); // ok, ok, ok ...
                this.setState(
                    {
                        fontSize: ++prevState.fontSize+"px"
                    }
                )
            },
            1000
        );
    }
    render() {
        let s1 = {
            fontSize: this.state.fontSize
        }
        return <p style={s1}>{this.props.text}</p>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Hello text="sadadadsdad" />,
    document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change a couple of things in your code:

- You are trying to access `prevState` inside `setState` but you are not using the `arrow` function thus `prevState` is `undefined` .
- You declared `fontSize` as a `string` in your initial state data so incrementing won't work since it should be a number.

Lastly, don't forget to [clear that interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval) in `componentWillUnmount`.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { fontSize: 20 };
  setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      fontSize: ++prevState.fontSize
    }));
  }, 1000);
}
```

See [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n7zrn2yo7j).