# React functional component: clearInterval() does not clear my interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a simple timer app. When the user clicks play the `handlePlayPause` function is called. I've created an `isRunning` boolean to check if the timer is already running. If it's not, the timer will start (this first part works), whilst if it is, the `pauseTimer` function is called. This last function switches `isRunning`  back to false and should clear the interval. However, the interval does not get cleared. Can you see what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

```js
export default function App() {
  const [sessionLength, setSessionLength] = useState(25)
  const [breakLength, setBreakLength] = useState(5)
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(25 * 60 * 1000)
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false)

  let intervalId = null

  let handlePlayPause = () => {
    if (!isRunning) {
      setTimeLeft(sessionLength * 60 * 1000)
      playTimer()
    } else if (isRunning) {
      pauseTimer()
    }
  }

  let playTimer = () => {
    setIsRunning(true)
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft(timeLeft => timeLeft - 1000)
      parseToMinuteSeconds(timeLeft)
    }, 1000)
  }

  let pauseTimer = () => {
    setIsRunning(false)
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }

  let resetAll = () => {
    setSessionLength(25)
    setBreakLength(5)
  }

  let parseToMinuteSeconds = timeInMilliseconds => {
    return //a string with the time in this format 00:00
  }

  return ( 
     <div className="App">
        <Background>
           <UpperMetalBand />
           <UpperPart />
           <LowerPart />
           <LowerMetalBand />
           <Wrapper>
              <Title>Pomodoro</Title>
              <Subtitle>TIMER</Subtitle>
              <PlayButton 
                  id="start_stop"
                  onClick = {handlePlayPause}
              >
                 <i className="fa fa-play" />
              </PlayButton>
              <Reload 
                 onClick={resetAll}
                 id="reset"
              >
                 <i className="fas fa-sync-alt" />
              </Reload>
              <Session 
                 setSessionLength={setSessionLength}
                 sessionLength={sessionLength}
              />
              <Break 
                 setBreakLength={setBreakLength}
                 breakLength={breakLength}
              />
              <span id="time-label">
                 <Timer id="time-left">00:00</Timer>
              </span>
           </Wrapper>
        </Background>
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: would be nice if you provide a concise run-able example

Comment: Show us the `clearInterval` method if possible

Comment: @tomrlh `clearInterval` is part of the browser API, same as `setInterval`.  [see more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the problem is with how you store the interval id. when using function components and we want to store "instance" variables we can use the `useRef` hook.

```
   let intervalId = useRef(null)
  
  let handlePlayPause = () => {
   
    if (!isRunning) {
      setTimeLeft(sessionLength * 60 * 1000)
      playTimer()
    } else if (isRunning) {
      pauseTimer()
    }
  }

  let playTimer = () => {
    setIsRunning(true)
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('interval')
      setTimeLeft(timeLeft => timeLeft - 1000)
      parseToMinuteSeconds(timeLeft)
    }, 1000)
  }

    
  let pauseTimer = () => {
    setIsRunning(false)
    clearInterval(intervalId.current)
  }
```

There is a similar example to your use case on the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables)

Comment: That was it, I'll look more into useRef. thank you very much.