# What is the correct way to stop the setInterval in my function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to implement a countdown in a game. Therefore I wrote some code but the setInterval is not stopping when it hits the number of 0.

Can somebody help me rewriting my code?

Below you can find the code.

```
secondsNum = 10;

{
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(secondsNum);
  secondsNum--;;
  if (secondsNum === 0) {
    clearInterval();
    console.log('Time is up');
  }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. It appears this question has been asked and answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5978519/831878). Does that answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value returned from `setInterval` and pass it back to `clearInterval` when you want it to stop.  It might look like this:

```
secondsNum = 10;
var timerID = 0;

timerID = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(secondsNum);
    secondsNum--;
    if (secondsNum === 0) {
        clearInterval(timerID);
        console.log('Time is up');
    }
}, 1000);
```