# Trying to store data in a clicker website

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am trying to store a variable called `score` that you use again and again no matter when you refresh. What I cannot figure out is what would be the code for that. I tried some ways but none of them seem to work at all.

This is for my clicker website. But when I try using JavaScript to store it, it does not work with `window.onload` and as well as `onload=`. Also my load maybe is right because I have a `score = data` with a `document.getElementById('points').innerHTML = score;`.

My code is shown below:

```
var score = 0;

setInterval(SaveData, 10);

setInterval(Click, 1000); // Every full second allow clicking ONE point.

function Click() {
  score++;
  document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = score;
    clearInterval(Click);
  }
}

function SaveData() {
  // What saves the variable score
  localStorage['save'] = btoa(JSON.stringify(score));
}

function LoadData() {
  score = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['save']))
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = score;
}

window.onload = function() {
  // When the window loads do this
  LoadData();
};
```

Comment: Looks like you should be using methods on `window.localStorage` rather than treating it as an array. For example, `window.localStorage.setItem('save', score);` and  `window.localStorage.getItem('save');`

Comment: So you mean that I need to not do the bracket array? If I did that, how would I put that in a ```.innerHTML``` to show the score?

Comment: No different. It would just be `score = window.localStorage.getItem('save');` instead of `score = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['save']))`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage for simple examples. I suggest you also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval because you aren't using clearInterval correctly either. These are basic issues which you could have solved by checking documentation and examples more carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line in `SaveData()`:

```
localStorage['save'] = btoa(JSON.stringify(score));
```

to this:

```
localStorage.setItem('save', btoa(JSON.stringify(score)));
```

and this line in `LoadData()`:

```
score = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['save']))
```

to this:

```
score = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage.getItem('save')));
```

Also, there is no need to update the event with every click. You can move that code out of the `Click()` function:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = score;
  clearInterval(Click);
}

function Click() {
  score++;
}
```

And you pass to `clearInterval()` the ID value that you get back from `setInterval()`, not a function reference. Something like:

```
var timer = setInterval(Click, 1000);
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I was typing just that. And then typing an example for that :)