# localStorage in my clicker game that is not working

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I have a website using localStorage. How ever when I run it I see NaN or the normal score (0).

The score is a value for my clicker game, when they click on the objective it gives them points.

For now, NaN is just no progress on my website.

If you want to see the website: [here is the Website.](https://button-presser.glitch.me/)

Does anyone know how to fix my JavaScript code?

```js
setInterval(500, SaveData);

function SaveData() {
  localStorage.setItem('save', score);
  localStorage.setItem('save', btoa(JSON.stringify(score)));  
}
function LoadData() {
  score = window.localStorage.getItem('save');
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = score;
}
window.onload = function()  {
LoadData();
}
```

EDIT: It looks like I have to check if its null

Comment: can you provide some context like what is the value for `score` ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the score variable please? What data type is it?

Comment: score variable with localStorage

Comment: NaN, MA==, or 0.

Comment: Why use `btoa()` on a JSON string for storage?

Comment: Try to do a console.log on your score to inspect it's value before saving it. Gosh, why can't people learn to use console.log?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to store data in a clicker website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175822/trying-to-store-data-in-a-clicker-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work here due to sandbox restrictions, but see on https://jsfiddle.net/tevemadar/Ln70r4bu/ - type anything into the textfield, close the tab, open link again and the text will be there.

```js
function save(){
    localStorage.setItem("save",stuff.value);
}
stuff.value=localStorage.getItem("save");
```

```html
<input type="text" id="stuff" oninput="save()">
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this ...

```
setInterval(500, SaveData);

function SaveData() {
  var scoreParse = parseFloat(score);
  if (isNaN(scoreParse)) {
   throw “not a number”;    
  }
  localStorage.setItem('save', score);
}
function LoadData() {
  score = window.localStorage.getItem('save');
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = score;
}
window.onload = function()  {
  LoadData();
}
```

Comment: Hey, on glitch, this code does not work. Could you improve it?

Comment: @JohnDoe since you have only provided limited details on what the initial value of “score” is, I cannot really provide any further examples. I have assumed that this value is a number, since you referenced NaN. It is odd that you btoa and stringified json object but do not atob it on the way out.