# How should I declare a variable that will have the value of setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I was looking at a question and someone answer it with the code bellow and in the comments someone said

> I think instead of assigning `undefined` we should assign `0` to `this.tm`. As it's time interval and it should not be `undefined`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);       

    this.tm; // With what value should this be declared?
}

timerInterval = () => {        
    this.tm = setInterval(() => {
            ...
    }, 1000);
}

render(){
    return(...)
}
```

So this made me wonder, what value should it be declared? Changing from `undefined` to `0` makes any difference?

A reference from docs or something like that would be good to explain it. I couldn't find any.

Comment: what do you need `this.tm` for? To `clearInterval`?

Comment: you don't need to define `this.tm` in `state`. or you can define `this.tm = 0`, because it's value keep increasing as time passes by. you can `console.log(this.tm)` inside `setInterval()` to know more about it's updated value

Comment: @marzelin I need `this.tm` so I can clear the interval later

Comment: Better if you can share a link to the question. Also, no need to 'declare' `tm` in constructor. You can directly use `this.tm`.

Comment: May be this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval

Comment: There is nothing wrong with declaring an `undefined` property. In your use case your only declaring `tm` inside constructor (could be directly inside class body) to make it available inside `didMount` or `willUnmount` scopes right? It's usually a good practice to initalize a class attribute but in your specific use case won't cause any problems at all

Comment: you can follow this https://medium.com/@650egor/react-30-day-challenge-day-1-simple-timer-df85d0867553

Comment: thanks to all, now it's much more clear. @SaimaHaji sugestion helped alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, combining all the comments

- I don't need to declare it in the constructor, I can just use `this.tm` normally. If I declare it, it's only as a good practice to make the code more clear.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978560/9119186) have the correct explanation on why it's better to set it to `0`, but only in the browser. If it's a node environment, it's better to set it as null.

  > On browsers, the handle is guaranteed to be a number that isn't equal to 0; therefore, 0 makes a handy flag value for "no timer set". (Other platforms may return other values; NodeJS's timer functions return an object, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to keep the `intervalID` is to clear the interval. `clearInterval(intervalID)` (as well as `clearTimeout(intervalID)`) will clear the interval or timeout that was set with the ID `intervalID`, but **will do nothing if `null`, `undefined`** or anything else (such as an invalid or no longer active ID) is passed to them.

So you are free to either initialize your variable with `null` or not initialize it at all.