# JavaScript syntax for function

Tags: javascript, function

Can someone explain me the following JS syntax:

```
  setInterval(function() {
    this.age++; // |this| refers to the global object
  }, 1000);
```

I'm a C programmer and I do not understand the end (, 1000).

Comment: [developer.mozilla.org is a very good resource for this type of thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: Please do a modicum of research before asking. [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: Please refer to a javascript tutorial, and the related [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Answer (score 1):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is a built-in function that executes a block of code repeatedly with a 
delay in between. It has two required arguments:

1. Function to be executed (you can think of it as similar to a function pointer in C)
2. Time in milliseconds to wait between executions

So the "1000" is simply the second argument and it means the passed function is executed every second.

Comment: setInterval can take more than two arguments. It describes them in the link you included.

Comment: Do you feel those arguments are relevant to the question asked?

Comment: They are relevant to giving an answer to the question that is factually correct since the answer you gave enumerated the arguments. You gave an exact number that was wrong. You could have just said "The first two arguments are..."

Comment: I changed it to "two required arguments".

Comment: good on ya. upvoted

Answer (score 0):

The callback function (first argument) will execute after every 1000ms.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in C, functions in javascript are first class citizens, meaning that they can be used the same way as a regular variable.

```
  setInterval(function() {
    this.age++; // |this| refers to the global object
  }, 1000);
```

What we have here are two things going on.

1. An anonymous function is being passed as a callback parameter.
2. An integer is being passed as the second parameter.

The setInterval function will accept a callback as the first parameter, which is usually a function that executes after X amount of time.

The X amount of time is defined by the second parameter, which is an integer value defined in milliseconds.

Comment: The first parameter is not "usually" a function, it is always a function, right? That is what the MDN [documentation for setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) says anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `setInterval` is a function. This is a callback function that `setInterval` will execute.

JavaScript treats functions as first class citizens, such that they can be passed as arguments. In this example, it tells `setInterval` what to execute in one second.

Answer (score -1):

This is the kind of question that would be better answered merely by going to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) to check the [documentation for setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) where a quick cursory glance will tell you that 1000 refers to a delay of 1000ms the method will wait before running the function passed in the first parameter again.

I don't want to be rude, but for a question that can be answered by reading the API documentation for the parameter of the method you are using, StackOverflow should probably not be your first resource.

Comment: I understand, but I didn't knew that setInterval was a kind of built-in function.

Comment: What did you think it was then? As a tip, if you don't understand something in the code for a native web technology like HTML, CSS, or JS, you can always just search MDN for it and they will have documentation. MDN should almost always be your first resource.