# Javascript setInterval and closeInterval inside a for loop that triggers an xhr request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, setinterval, clearinterval

I've been reading all sort of similar questions but I cannot find help for my specific case, I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this problem I'm facing as I'm not so proficient with JS and AJAX.

I have a HTML page that shows a series of items in a table:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col">Crawl</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            
            <tr>
            <td class="crawl" task_id="6094590cc05111ea872d6003089f5d66">627b1b39-1f37-48aa-9a19-e6955470d80e</td>
            <td>07/07/2020</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td id="crawl-status-6094590cc05111ea872d6003089f5d66"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success">See analysis</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
            <td class="crawl" task_id="0d44e2dac05311ea93bc6003089f5d66">bc7b0ce3-9bfb-41ff-b88b-6415cb6a1091</td>
            <td>07/07/2020</td>
            <td>Y</td>
            <td id="crawl-status-0d44e2dac05311ea93bc6003089f5d66"></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success">See analysis</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </td>
            </tr>
            
        
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

Each line is basically a crawl of a site which is running or has been run in the past, hence in the column "Status" we can have 3 options: "pending", "running" and "finished". I've created a xhr call to an endpoint to get the status of each crawl and populates the status cell in the table:

```
crawls = document.getElementsByClassName("crawl")


var i;
for (i = 0; i < crawls.length; i++) {
    
    crawl_item = crawls[i]

    // Grab task ID for each crawl
    task_id = crawl_item.getAttribute("task_id")

    // Check crawl status
    crawlStatus(task_id)

}







// Get the crawl status by making a GET request to the API URL
function crawlStatus(task_id){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const method = 'GET'
    const url = '/crawler/crawl-status/' + task_id + "/" 

    const responseType = "json"
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')

    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method,url)

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH","XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
            

    xhr.onload = function(){

        var serverResponse = xhr.response

        crawl_status_cell = document.getElementById("crawl-status-"+ task_id)
        crawl_status_cell.innerText = serverResponse.status



   
        
    }

    xhr.send()
}
```

This works correctly, but then I am not able to repeat this request every 2-3 seconds to check the new status. If initial status is "pending" or "running", the function should check again until the status is "finished" and then stop.

I've tried using setInterval but I am not able to clear it with clearIntervals afterwards. The problem is that I don't know in advance how many lines there will be in the table so I cannot fire the crawlStatus function separately for each one of them.

I have tried a lot of combinations, the latter of which is the following:

```
function crawlStatus(task_id){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    const method = 'GET'
    const url = '/crawler/crawl-status/' + task_id + "/" 

    const responseType = "json"
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken')

    xhr.responseType = responseType
    xhr.open(method,url)

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH","XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest")
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
            

    xhr.onload = function(){

        var serverResponse = xhr.response

        crawl_status_cell = document.getElementById("crawl-status-"+ task_id)
        crawl_status_cell.innerText = serverResponse.status

        if(serverResponse.status === "pending" || serverResponse.status === "running"){
            setInterval("crawlStatus(task_id)", 500);
        } else {
            
            clearInterval("crawlStatus(task_id))
            
        }

   
        
    }

    xhr.send()
}
```

Has someone faced a similar issue and can help me sort it out? Also, if you know a best way of doing it feel free to suggest it!

Thanks a lot to whoever will try to help me! :)

Askew

Comment: I think you just want the onload function to trigger a single new "crawlStatus" and not one every 0.5 seconds, so try using setTimeout instead of setInterval.  Or, simply call the function again directly `if (serverResponse.status....) { crawlStatus(task_id) }`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, actually I do need to check every X seconds each crawl because I need to know when a crawl has finished to do some more tasks with it.

Comment: If you use `setInterval` on every `onload` event, then you will have so many timers as `onload` events happened. You need to keep track of all `setInterval`s with an `object` or `array` of their respective handles, and clear them all. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval) I also think, you'd be much better off with a `setTimeout` in the `onload` event, or a `setInterval` at the beginning of your `crawlStatus(task_id)` function (that is cleared when the `status` is not `pending`/`running`). But always use a handler, otherwise it won't be cleared.

Comment: I've tried with setTimeout but it does not seem to be what I'm looking for, as it fires the function after X seconds. What I need is to run the AJAX script every 5 seconds to check if the status if still running/pending or is finished, and do this for each crawl listed on the table. The difficulty for me is that since I don't know in advance how many crawls I will have, I need to do a for loop and so I cannot store a unique variable with the setInterval timer. As a consequence I cannot clear it

Comment: An update on this: I’ve decided to go for websockets to perform this task as it seemed like a more robust solution.