# How to clearInterval?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

[EDIT: Thanks so much for the help everyone. I see that the question is marked down by some because it doesn't show enough research, etc. Apologies, and thank you for your patience! I'm new to coding and stackoverflow--not sure of the rules or etiquette yet.]

Why is this not stopping after the first 'DONE'? Any easy fix?

```
function countdown(num) {
  let n = num;
  function dec() {
    if (n > 1) {
      n--;
      console.log(n);
    } else {
      clearInterval(dec);
      console.log('DONE!');
    }
  }
  
  setInterval(dec, 1000);
}
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: `clearInterval` takes the intervalid as the parameter.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clearInterval requires the interval id that setInterval returns.

```js
function countdown(num) {
  let n = num, id;
  function dec() {
    if (n > 1) {
      n--;
      console.log(n);
    } else {
      clearInterval(id);
      console.log('DONE!');
    }
  }
  
  id = setInterval(dec, 1000);
}

countdown(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must store a reference to the return value from the timer (which identifies it) and then you use that reference to clear the timer later. You are attempting to pass the callback function as the reference to clear.

See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for full details.

```js
function countdown(num) {
  let timer = null; // <-- This will store the timer id
  let n = num;
  function dec() {
    if (n > 1) {
      n--;
      console.log(n);
    } else {
      clearInterval(timer); // <-- Pass the ID to cancel
      console.log('DONE!');
    }
  }
  
  timer = setInterval(dec, 1000); // <-- Capture the return value
}

countdown(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
function countdown(num) {
  let n = num;
  function dec() {
    if (n > 1) {
      n--;
      console.log(n);
    } else {
      clearIntervalABC();
      console.log('DONE!');
    }
  }
  function clearIntervalABC() {
    clearInterval(inter);
  }
  const inter = setInterval(dec, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear timers, not functions

```js
function countdown(num) {
    let n = num;
    function dec() {
        if (n > 1) {
            n--;
            console.log(n);
        } else {
            clearInterval(a);
            console.log('DONE!');
        }
    }

    const a = setInterval(dec, 1000);
}
countdown(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

To extend other people's good answers, the following code also does the trick in a slightly more compact manner:

```js
let countdown = num => {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (num <= 1) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('DONE');
    } else {
      num--;
      console.log(num);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

countdown(5);
```