# Change setInterval property to augment game sensibility not working (js)

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am creating a game and I would like to change the setInterval property in order to augment game sensibility of a spaceship (shown in code as setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40)). I placed a range slider that goes from position 1, 2 and 3. Here is the code:

Range Slider:

```
<input type="range" id="sensibilty" min="1" max="3" value="2">
```

Sensibility

```
const loop = function() {
if (keys[37] || keys[65]) {pos.left -= 10}
if (keys[39] || keys[68]) {pos.left += 10}
if (keys[38] || keys[80]) {pos.top -= 1}
if (keys[40] || keys[75]) {pos.top += 1}}
let sens = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40);
let sensibilty = document.getElementById("sensibilty").value;
if (sensibilty == "1") {clearInterval(sens); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 30)}
else if (sensibilty == "3") {clearInterval(sens); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60)}
```

This code is not working, any idea to change setInterval values? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Comment: You need to keep a reference to the currently running interval and clear *that* instead of `loop`.

Comment: That does not change anything, the posted answer as well as the duplicate both answer the question with and without the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store your interval so you can clear it.

```
let interval = setInterval(loop, 1000 / 40) //THAT IS SENSIBILITY

if (sensibilty == 1) {clearInterval(interval); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 30)} 
else if (sensibilty == 3) {clearInterval(interval); setInterval(loop, 1000 / 60)}
```