# Countdown Timer only stops when the page is refreshed

Tags: javascript

I borrowed a countdown timer code from stackoverflow and it was working fine until I decided to add another code from stackoverflow that uses localStorage so the timer will continue even after the page refreshes. My timer should stop when the totalSeconds is 0 but because there is a localStorage, it doesn't know what the totalSeconds' value should be. Is my if statement for totalSeconds correct? It only works when the page refreshes but doesn't recognize the timer as it counts down.

```
  quiztime: res.data[x].Time; //This was a variable from my get function that based on user input
              
           var totalSeconds = 0;

            if (this.quizTime != 0) {

            if(localStorage.getItem("totalSeconds")){
                  totalSeconds = localStorage.getItem("totalSeconds");  
              } else {
                  totalSeconds = this.quizTime;
              }
            }
             
            if(totalSeconds <= 0){ 
                    setTimeout(this.submitMyAnswer(), 3000);
                  } else {
                    setTimeout(setTime, 1000);
                  }
           
              var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
              var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
              setInterval(setTime, 1000);
                

                function setTime() {
                --totalSeconds;
                secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
                minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
                localStorage.setItem("totalSeconds", totalSeconds);
                }
 
              function pad(val) {
                var valString = val + "";
                if (valString.length < 2) {
                  return "0" + valString;
                } else {
                  return valString;
                }
              }

              window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                s;
                e.returnValue = "";
              });
        
            
        });
    },
```

Comment: Declare `totalSeconds` outside the `if (this.quizTime != 0)` block

Comment: Okay I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the return value of `setTimeout` in a variable. Then, you just clear the interval with `clearTimeout` method.

eg:

```js
const milisecs = 1000 // one sec

const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
 // do some stuff here
}, milisecs)

// after doing other stuff... farewell dear timeout, we won't forget you
clearTimeout(timeout)
```

Same thing goes for `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what should I do if I want to stop the execution if my totalSeconds is equal to 0? Like on the timer, but without refreshing? I need to edit out my question because I am a bit confused with my question actually.

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code.

**Do not use parenthesis `()` with `setTmeout` callback** (`setTimeout(this.submitMyAnswer(), 3000);`). As it will invoke return value from submitMyAnswer() after `timeout`. I guess you are supposed to call `submitMyAnswer` after `3 seconds` so just use

`setTimeout(this.submitMyAnswer, 3000);`

---

Another thing is you want to clear interval after `totalSeconds` is become 0. To stop interval you should be using [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) also refer [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval).

In your case you have to assign return value from `setInterval` to any object, say `interval`, and when add condition in `setTime` when `totalSeconds <= 0` then clearInterval(interval). Your updated code would be like below.

Refer [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), you can pass parameter to with `setInterval`.

Comment out below code as it won't be needed. Call `submitMyAnswer` from `setTime` inside `if` condition as per below code.

```
// Comment below code. It will not needed.
//if (totalSeconds <= 0) {
//  setTimeout(this.submitMyAnswer, 3000);
//} else {
//  setTimeout(setTime, 1000);
//}

// assign return value from setInterval to object
// pass this.submitMyAnswer function as parameter so it can be invoked when totalSeconds become 0, Note : Do not use () as this.submitMyAnswer()
var interval = setInterval(setTime, 1000, this.submitMyAnswer);

// get callback function submitMyAnswer in parameter to invoke when time elapsed.
function setTime(submitMyAnswer) {
  --totalSeconds;
  secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
  minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  localStorage.setItem("totalSeconds", totalSeconds);

  // clear interval once totalSeconds is 0
  if (totalSeconds <= 0) {
    clearInterval(interval);

    // call submitMyAnswer() once totalSeconds become 0.
    // do not use this.submitMyAnswer(), simply use submitMyAnswer()
    submitMyAnswer();
  }
}
```

Comment: So, if I cleared the interval, will it count the totalSecond as my quizTime? I wanted to execute a function once the quizTime expires but since it is in localStorage, it only executes it upon refresh.

Comment: You want `submitMyAnswer` to execute when `totalSeconds` become 0?

Comment: Yes, once the totalSeconds from either quizTime or as a localStorage data expires, it should execute the function. The quizTime is the main time while the localStorage is the remaining time. Sorry if it's confusing, I thought that both are the same thing because it's both declared on totalSeconds.

Comment: I am getting an error on my submitMyAnswer function. It says it's not a function.

Comment: It might be issue with scope of your function, please check updated answer.