# JS how to clear setInterval and not allow setInterval to repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, setinterval

Im making a simple HTML/CSS/JS program where traffic lights appear. There are two buttons - "auto" and "manual". If you click "auto", you're supposed to see the traffic lights flick through the colours by itself. I achieved this with setInterval. If you click "manual", you're meant to be able to switch control to manual and only change the colour manually. I'm very new to Javascript and the problem im currently running into is that when I go from Auto to Manual, the setInterval continues to run, so the traffic light changes colour as soon as you press manual, but the lights also continue to change by themselves. In addition, it is possible to click the "auto" button twice, meaning the colours begin to change rapidly the more times you press it, because setInterval starts getting called multiple times.

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Traffic Lights</title>
    <link rel="retylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/restyle.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="traffic.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="auto">Auto</a>
    <div class="trafficlight">
      <div class="circle red" color="red"></div>
      <div class="circle orange" color="orange"></div>
      <div class="circle green" color="green"></div>
    </div>
    <a class="manual">Manual</a>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="traffic.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color:#eb3456;
  min-height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.circle{
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
  height:80px;
  width:80px;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.trafficlight{
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:30px;
  width:150px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
}

.circle.red{
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px red;
}
.circle.orange{
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px orange;
}
.circle.green{
  background-color: green;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px 10px green;
}
a{
  background-color: #A9A9A9;
  color: white;
  padding: 7px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
a:hover, a:active{
  background-color: #545252;
}
```

JS:

```
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
const auto = document.querySelector(".auto");
const manual = document.querySelector(".manual");
let active=0;
function changeLight(){
  circles[active].className="circle";
  active++;
  if(active>2){
    active=0;
  }
  const current=circles[active];

  current.classList.add(current.getAttribute("color"));
}
auto.onclick = function(){
  setInterval(changeLight,1000);
}
manual.onclick = function(){
  clearInterval();
  changeLight();
}
```

I've tried looking it up and I cant find anything on how to stop allowing .onclick being able to be used twice, or why clearInterval() doesnt work when manual is pressed. Any help on how to get these two buttons to work by switching control between computer and user would be great - this is my first day using JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this script. I think this is what you need

```
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");
const auto = document.querySelector(".auto");
const manual = document.querySelector(".manual");
let active=0;

let isAuto= false;
let autofunction;

function changeLight(){
  circles[active].className="circle";
  active++;
  if(active>2){
    active=0;
  }
  const current=circles[active];

  current.classList.add(current.getAttribute("color"));
}
auto.onclick = function(){
    isAuto = true

    if(autofunction == undefined){
     autofunction =  setInterval(function(){
        if(isAuto){
            circles[active].className="circle";
            active++;
            if(active>2){
              active=0;
            }
        const current=circles[active];

        current.classList.add(current.getAttribute("color"));
        }


    },1000);
  }
  
 
}
manual.onclick = function(){
/*   clearInterval(); */
isAuto = false
  changeLight();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign setInterval assignment to one variable, this will hold the interval id which you can clear later, for example:

```
const lightItrvl;
auto.onclick = function(){
  lightItrvl = setInterval(changeLight,1000);
}
```

now you can use clearInterval method to clear this setInterval instance

```
clearInterval(lightItrvl)
```

browser can have multiple setInterval instances and clearInterval() wouldn't be a appropriate syntax for that, hence you need to pass the intervalId to this method. This is missing in your code.

Please check this already answered question on SO
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978560/6351979

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue of having two buttons with separate control, however it still duplicates when "auto" is clicked twice - it goes very fast if clicked multiple times, because clicking it doesn't overwrite the variable, but instead for some reason adds to it. Can someone please explain why and give a suggestion on fixing this?