# How do I use clearInterval method

Tags: javascript

```js
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  const startDate = new Date();
  const endtDate = new Date("June 11 ,2021 10:12:00");
  let timeDiffernceObj = getTimeDiffernce(startDate, endtDate);
  timerDayEl.textContent = timeDiffernceObj.rDays;
  timerHourEl.textContent = timeDiffernceObj.rHours;
  timerMinEl.textContent = timeDiffernceObj.rMin;
  timerSecEl.textContent = timeDiffernceObj.rSec;

}, 1000);

clearInterval(timeDiffernceObj);
```

Comment: call clearInterval(timer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO. You can use the following to clear the set interval.

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: You need to put the ```clearInterval``` function call inside some other event depending upon your requirements  e.g a button click etc. Right now what it does is that it sets the interval and immediately clears it as well. So you can not see anything happening.

Comment: how about I just want it to be 0 for all the values without having an event

Comment: sorry I can not understand what you want. Can you explain your use case more?

Comment: I want the counter to stop when it reaches the endDate