# Unable to make a timer stop.. (js)

Tags: javascript, html, web

hi im doing a quiz app and i want it to count 10 sec for example and then go to another question but when I try to do: if(document.getElementById("timer_sec").innerHTML ==0).....
it doesnt work.

````
HTML":
<h1 class="hud-main-text" id="timer_sec">
 10
</h1>
js:
startGame = () => {
  document.getElementById("timer_sec").innerHTMl=10;
  questionCounter = 0;
  score = 0;
  availableQuesions1 = [...questions1];
  availableQuesions2 = [...questions2];
  availableQuesions3 = [...questions3];
  availableQuesions4 = [...questions4];

  setInterval(
    () => document.getElementById("timer_sec").innerHTML--,
    1000
  );
  getNewQuestion();
};```
````

Comment: use `clearInterval` for that

Comment: but how do i use it?   to make it stop when it comes to 0

Comment: you check if the value is zero, then use [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) <= some documentation to read about clearInterval

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-to-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Comment: when i do it like this it wont stop: