# How to change places in an Array using React and useEffect?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, algorithm, use-effect

There's a list of 5 elements. Per default, the list (array) should show ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]. Every second the elements should rotate by one position:

List after 1 second: ["B", "C", "D", "E", "A"];

After 2 seconds: ["C", "D", "E", "A", "B"];

After 3 seconds: ["D", "E", "A", "B", "C"];

I'm learning and I need help. How would you solve this problem? This is my incorrect solution:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState();
  const [letter, setLetter] = useState([]);

  let array = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = () =>
      setInterval(() => {
        array.push(array.shift());
        setLetter(array);
       }, 1000);

    interval();

    return clearInterval(interval);
  }, [array]);

  return (
    <div className="center">
      <input
        type="text"
        value={term}
        onChange={(e) => setTerm(e.target.value)}
      />
      {letter &&
        letter.map((l, i) => {
          return (
            <ul key={l}>
              <li>{l[0]}</li>
              <li>{l[1]}</li>
              <li>{l[1]}</li>
              <li>{l[3]}</li>
              <li>{l[4]}</li>
            </ul>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm just a learner, I'm stuck, and I need help. It changes rapidly, like every 50ms.

I'll analyze the answer and learn from it because I can't do it by myself.

Comment: [`clearInterval` takes the interval id (returned by calling `setInterval`), not a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5978519/1218980)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you avoid modifying your array.  Rather than using `push` and `shift`, generate a new version of the array by `arr => [...arr .slice (1), arr [0]]` or using `concat`:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [letters, setLetters] = useState (["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout (
      () => setLetters (arr => arr .slice (1) .concat (arr [0])), 
      1000
    )
    return () => clearTimeout (timer)
 })

  return (<div>{letters .join (' ')}</div>)
}

ReactDOM .render (<App/>, document .getElementById ("main"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Modifying data only through the setter makes things much more consistent.

Note that this will work fine without returning the `clearTimeout`, but it's probably a good habit to be in.

Comment: Wow, what a great solution. Your answer is the best. Thank you. 

Can you help me with something else? When I try to reach the Apple Music API (I'm using Axios and setting params) extra characters get added to the URL, so I get a 404 response. The URL should go like this `: https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=eminem`, but it gets turned into `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=&0=eminem`. The extra is `=&0`. Why is this happening? I'll make a separate question if you're willing and share the link here, that is if you're willing to help me.

Comment: Just ask another question, after you've done research yourself.  If I happen to see it and am interested, I may try to help.  Feel free to add a link to that question in the comments here, but no guarantees.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71800952/inserting-data-initially-at-the-bottom-of-a-table-how-that-be-achieved

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that you have a `useEffect` attached to the changes of `array` which changes multiple times inside the interval callback.

1. Change: array.shift() -> Triggers the `useEffect`
2. Change: array.push() -> Also triggers the `useEffect`

This compounds and starts changing the array rapidly.

I would suggest working with an array copy or something of the sort.

```
setInterval(() =>
  let copy = […array];
  copy.push(copy.shift());
  setLetter(copy);
  array = copy
}, 1000);
```

Just another suggestion. I would also try to not use the extra `array` variable as that data is already stored in the `letter`.
Here is how I would go about doing this.

```
const [letter, setLetter] = useState(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() =>
    let copy = […letter];
    copy.push(copy.shift());
    setLetter(copy);
  }, 1000);
}, [letter]);
```

I didn’t test this, so I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't understand it. It starts normally, and then it starts going faster, and then rapidly again. Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi. I edited the example and it should be working now. Instead of `setInterval` I just used `setTimeout` which triggers only once, after the set amount of time and we don’t have to clear it.

Comment: YES, my man. Thank you so freaking more. Now, it works flawlessly. Have a good one. Thank you once again.