# Inserting data initially at the bottom of a table. How that be achieved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, datatable

I need to insert data that's coming from iTunes API at the very end of a table. The first album (in my case) goes at the very end, and the next one goes at the end and the previous one gets "pushed" to a place above, and so forth.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far?

Comment: You've certainly been around long enough to know that this isn't much of a question.  Please share your attempt, describe your research, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `push` then it will automatically add items at the end of an array, unlike `unshift` which adds items at the beginning.
If you are still not getting the desired result then try some kind of sorting, like:

```
array.sort((a,b)=> {
//sorting logic based on your data
})
```

You have to share more info about your problem before I can be precise.