# repeat task as long as component is shown

Tags: angular

I would like to repeat a task in my Angular component regularly. My first attempt was such a setInterval construction in the constructor. The problem is that the execution does not stop when I hide the component and when I show it it even executes 2x.
So what is the right way to execute a task WHILE a component is shown (and stop if component ist not shown anymore)?

```
   // in constructor of component
          setInterval(() => {
    // do something
         
          }, intervall * 1000);
```

Comment: Use clearInterval when the condition is satisfied, i.e. the component is show. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5978519/5468463. If the component is the parent, i.e. routing, you still can use (activate)

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm. clearInterval() in ngOnDestroy() did the job. Sad that I can not accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
subscription : Subscription ;
ngOnInit()
{
   const observbles = new Observable(sub => {
    //do something.
   this.subscription = observbles.subscribe(x => ....);
});
}

ngOnDestroy()
{
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

NOTE : Do your actions in ngOnInit() and to end it implement it 
 in ngOnDestroy()
```

It will repeat the task until your are in that component and
destroy it when you leave that component I have displayed a demo of
observable

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid obviously I am already voted down. I can't get it to work - how would it look if I wanted to print "hello" into the console every second?
Thanks for the help despite the seemingly not well asked question

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vegas answer (thanks again!) I solved it this way:

```ts
      myIntervall = null;
      ngOnInit() {
        this.myIntervall = setInterval(() => {
          console.log(
            'I am called every two seconds as long as this component is shown'
          );
        }, 2 * 1000);
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.myIntervall);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer, you can then subscribe and unsubscribe in the `ngOnInit` and the `ngOnDestroy`.

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  interval = 5;
  timerSub!: Subscription;
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.timerSub = timer(0, this.interval * 1000).subscribe();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.timerSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```