# Clear setInterval before starting a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding a tower of hanoi game, in which the timer should get reset every time a div or in my case a shape is dragged. But the problem is that when i call the setInterval function a second time then the counters start to overlap. What i want is that the old timer get cleared and the latest one keep on running.

```
function timer() {
    var timeleft = 10;
    var downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        alert("Game over! You ran out of time\nPlay again ?");
        location.reload();
      } else {
        timeleft -= 1;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

This is the code for setInterval function.

```
function Drag() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
      stack: $(".draggable"),
      helper: "clone",
      start: function () {
        timer();
        var parentNode = "#" + this.parentNode.id;
        platforms.push(parentNode);
        var shape = "#" + this.id;
        sequence.push(shape);
        var shapeParent = this.closest(".holder").id;
        shapeParent = "#" + shapeParent;
      },
    });
  }
```

And this is from where i am calling the timer/setInterval function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use setInterval and clearInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978519/how-can-i-use-setinterval-and-clearinterval)

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal no it does not, what i need is to clear the old setInterval and start a new one every time a div is dragged

Comment: 1) Nothing about this is anything to do with `async` 2) You only clear the timer when `timeleft <= 0`, not whenever the drag starts under any condition as your description states. It seems like the solution is to simply move the timer clear call to outside the condition...? If that's not what you're asking, then we would need to see a more complete example of the logic - ideally in an executable snippet.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah it had nothing to do with async, thank you though the solution proposed by Roko works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronicity has nothing to do with your problem. You're just not clearing the interval before starting a new one.

- Define the timeout variable outside of the function
- Clear it inside the drag `start` method as well - or simply inside the top of the `timer()` function:

```js
// Define it in the outer scope
var downloadTimer;

function timer() {

    // Clear ongoing (if any)
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);

    var timeleft = 10;
    downloadTimer = setInterval(function () {
      if (timeleft <= 0) {
        // Clear when game over
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        alert("Game over! You ran out of time\nPlay again ?");
        location.reload();
      } else {
        timeleft -= 1;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timeleft;
      }
    }, 1000);
}

function Drag() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
      stack: $(".draggable"),
      helper: "clone",
      start: function () {

        // Optionally you can clear it here:
        // clearInterval(downloadTimer);

        timer();
        var parentNode = "#" + this.parentNode.id;
        platforms.push(parentNode);
        var shape = "#" + this.id;
        sequence.push(shape);
        var shapeParent = this.closest(".holder").id;
        shapeParent = "#" + shapeParent;
      },
    });
  }
```